# Enum deserializing when the enum declaration has changed

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

If I serialize a class with enum of certain value, but when deserializing I have modified the enum declaration. The `int` value of serialized enum would correspond to the new enum name, not the originally serialized one.

So does the deserializer compare the actual enum name for me, or will it return different one?

Comment: In C#, enum just glorified integer. It will serialized as integer and deserialized from integer too.

Comment: It does not compare the name but the value instead. C# enums can be integer, long, etc.

Comment: So the only way to ensure version compatibility is to serialize something else (e.g. string) and then maintain a dictionary that maps string to enum, for example?